# Query sub documents in array of parent document

Tags: mongoose

db.animals

```
{'animal':'monkey',
 'quantity:3
 'id' : 001}
{'animal':'pig',
 'quantity:5
 'id' : 002}
{'animal':'cow',
 'quantity:3
 'id' : 003}
```

db.people

```
{'person':'john',
 'have':[001, 003]} // objectId
```

How can I get animals of John?. I expect the result like this:

```
[{'animal':'monkey',
 'quantity:3
 'id' : 001},
{'animal':'cow',
 'quantity:3
 'id' : 003}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no joins in MongoDB so you have to do it in two steps.

In the shell:

```js
var john = db.people.findOne({person: 'john'})
db.animals.find({id: {$in: john.have}})
```